# JS how to add an attribute for each element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, decomposition

I'm very beginner in coding. Please help me with this:
I need to add an attribute 'name' to my array.
I got each element separately but don't know how to add attribute "name" to it :/ is it possible ?
Working with graphql an TS, I got this:
`"myTypes": [ "cat", "dog", "bird", "butterfly" ]`

and I need to become it like this :
`"myTypes": [ {name: "cat"}, {name:"dog"}, {name: "bird"}, {name: "butterfly"}]`

My code:
`const mydata = response.data.myTypes let names = Array.from(mydata).forEach((element: any) =>  console.log(element))`

thanks for your help !

Comment: You can use `mydata.map()` to change the strings into objects.

Comment: You could probably find what you are looking to by looking into Array.map(). Like `myData.map(e=>{return {name: e}})` or similar.

Comment: `mydata` should already an array so `Array.from(mydata)` is unnecessary. Have a look at `Array.prototype.map()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the map function it takes a callback that returns the new array with the modifications you made inside the map.
Also your callback should return the new array item everytime
it should be like this

```
const myNewTypes=myTypes.map((type)=>{return { name: type }})
```

Comment: oh yes It's working !! thank you very much ! I tried it before, but my syntaxe was wrong... thanks a lot :)

Comment: Would appreciate if you accept my answer :D